# mysql - left join и where

Tags: mysql, join

Существует две таблицы, которые требуется соединить при помощи left join, а также подсчитать сумму строк, удовлетворяющих некоторому условию. При использовании where left join превращается в inner join, так как where обрезает не существующие записи.

```
SELECT Person.PersonID, JobID, sum(JobTime) FROM Job, Person LEFT JOIN JobTime ON Person.PersonID=JobTime.PersonID WHERE Job.SprintID=1 AND Job.PersonID=Person.PersonID GROUP BY Person.PersonID;
+----------+-------+--------------+
| PersonID | JobID | sum(JobTime) |
+----------+-------+--------------+
|        1 |     1 |      2569980 |
|        2 |     2 |      7686475 |
|        3 |     3 |         NULL |
|        4 |     4 |      7816887 |
|        5 |     5 |      6721046 |
|        6 |     6 |         NULL |
+----------+-------+--------------+

SELECT Person.PersonID, JobID, sum(JobTime) FROM Job, Person LEFT JOIN JobTime ON Person.PersonID=JobTime.PersonID WHERE Job.SprintID=1 AND Job.PersonID=Person.PersonID AND DATE(JobDate) BETWEEN '2017-06-26' AND '2017-07-08' GROUP BY Person.PersonID;
+----------+-------+--------------+
| PersonID | JobID | sum(JobTime) |
+----------+-------+--------------+
|        1 |     1 |       354577 |
|        2 |     2 |       323180 |
|        4 |     4 |       341232 |
|        5 |     5 |       298533 |
+----------+-------+--------------+
```

Требуется сделать так, чтобы строки с null тоже были включены в таблицу.

Comment: jobDate из какой таблицы ? подозреваю, что из JobTime. Перенесите условия, задевающие эту таблицу из where в ON (или учтите в условии проверки, что поле может быть NULL)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что в ON можно добавлять условие, это решило мою проблему